# What video sharing services exist that facilitate sharing from a time within a video beyond YouTube?

Tags: video

I frequently need to share videos starting at specific times within videos.  YouTube is not always feasible and I'd like to know about other possible services that also have time sharing functionality so that viewers can click on the link and the video will start at that time stamp.

What such services exist for specific time frame video sharing?

Comment: Sorry, but this site does not accept questions asking for app recommendations. If you can re-frame your question to be about the problem you're trying to solve rather than finding the thing you believe is the solution, it may be on-topic here. See also: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VIMEO:**

> To share a video link that will begin playback at a specific point,
>   all you need to do is add a bit of code to the end of the URL. Just
>   add: `#t=` followed by the timecode of where you'd like playback to
>   begin.
>
> Here is an example where playback begins one minute and two seconds
>   into the video: `https://vimeo.com/81400335#t=1m2s`
>
> You can also use this parameter for embedded videos. To do this,
>   simply add `#t=(timestamp here)` to the end of the player URL in your
>   embed code. For example:
>
> `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/81400335#t=1m2s"`
>   `width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen`
>   `mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`
>
> If you're embedding a video and would like it to automatically start
>   playing, you can add the `?autoplay=1` parameter before `#t=` as shown in
>   this example:
>
> `<iframe`
>   `src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/81400335?autoplay=1#t=1m2s"`
>   `width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen`
>   `mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`

**DAILYMOTION:**

> parameter `start` number `0` - Specifies the time (in seconds) from
>   which the video should start playing.
>
> For a specific time just add `?start=xxxx` to your url. Where `xxxx`
>   is the starting time in seconds.
>
> Example: `http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1yp9ce?start=120` will start video
>   at 2 minute mark.

**TWITCH:**

> Just add `?t=_h_m_s` to the end of the url. Fill in the blanks with
>   the timestamp.
>
> For example, if you want to link to a spot that is at 01:18:42, your
>   link would look like:
>   `http://www.twitch.tv/floe/b/541334138?t=01h18m42s`
>
> You can also drop starting zeros, so 01:29:19 could also look like
>   `?t=1h29m19s`. If the time is at 19:51, the link could use
>   `?t=19m51s`. This way there's no need to wade through hours of stream
>   to find something. Hope it helps.

**WISTIA:**

> To share your video at a specific time navigate to the Embed and Share
>   modal under the ▸ Video Actions menu. In the Embed & Share window,
>   select the Social Sharing option at the top. Under the URL you'll see
>   an option to Link to a specific time. Clicking the box will
>   automatically link to wherever you've paused the video. You can also
>   manually edit the time stamp.
>
> You can do this to any Wistia link by adding the `wtime=` string.
>   Examples:
>
> `https://support.wistia.com/medias/h1z3uqsjal?wtime=2`
>
> `https://support.wistia.com/medias/ktv95e6b2g?wtime=1m1s`

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.